# Loss of reputation because a "user was removed"

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, user-accounts

I just noticed that I lost 10 points of rep because "user was removed". I don't get it.

Comment: My guess is that someone deleted their account and part of that led to some reputation loss on your behalf (maybe they voted on one of your questions).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it

Comment: IIRC, you also lose reputation points in MO1.0 if someone deletes the account. But in MO1.0 the loss is "silent" (you don't get notified) and "asynchronous" (the loss may show up some time later when a reputation recalculation is triggered). The SE2 software make reputation computations much more real-time and transparent.

Comment: @WillieWong : I never had that happen to me on MO1.0 -- I think I would've noticed a sudden drop like that, no matter when it occurred.

Comment: There ought to be a "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your reputation history. Does it not show when you tick it?

Comment: @ToddTrimble It may mean also that no-one who has upvoted you had his or her account deleted while on MO1.0.... `:-)`

Comment: Thanks, Andras. I ticked it, but I don't see it.

Comment: Yes, Willie, I figured that.

Comment: @WillieWong (and Todd Trimble): it is my understanding that on MO1.0 rep recalcs essentially *only* happened, when a mod triggered it *manually* for some user, that is to say never for almost everybody. I know I had the points for some self or otherwise deleted answers for months or even years. Only upon the move did the rep go away.

Answer (score 15):

When a user is removed, their votes are removed as well. So the most likely explanation is that the user had voted for one of your answers and the reputation you gained from that vote was removed with the user.

The cause for deletion is usually either sock puppeting and vote fraud, or the user reqested to be deleted. In cases of high-reputation users with lots of votes, SE performs a different procedure that retains the votes.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the consequences of the recent upgrade to stackexchange software.  Maybe this aspect of the updated software doesn't always seem like an upgrade.  This happens from time to time on all stackexchange sites.  I once lost more than 200 reputation points on m.s.e. because of just one user being removed.  Who the user is, and which of your questions and answers are affected, is strictly secret, and that secrecy has been defended at length by a number of people.

Comment: The loss of reputation has always happened, the difference is that is it much more visible now that the reputation is instantly updated. Before that change users could have gone without a recalc that would show losses from deleted user and posts for months or years.