# Negative reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, specific-user

I found this in the "Users" listing

[image: nagetive]

What is negative reputation?

The profile for this user (who was last here 3 years ago) shows reputation 101.

Answer (score 4):

When looking at [users tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users) you can choose what to display - reputation, editors, voters, new users, moderators. And you can also use period on which you want to concentrate. (I am not really sure which period is chosen by default if you do not change anything.)

If you display reputation for week, month, etc., it is displayed as negative if the *reputation change* of that user was negative in a given week/month. You can check users with username containing "banach" and their reputation change for the current [week](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week&search=banach), [month](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month&search=banach), [quarter](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter&search=banach), [year](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year&search=banach) and [all time](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=banach). (The last one shows reputation of the users on the site. The other tabs correspond to reputation change in the chosen period.)

Comment: It seems that this particular user asked at least one questions - as he was [awarded student badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/2/student?userid=73705). I do not see the question there - but 10k+ users should be able to see also the question. (Most likely cause for losing 5 reputation points seems deletion of a question which had one upvote.)

Comment: Got it.  The amount the rep changed in the last month seems to be the default setting.  But in fact his current rep is 101, the same as after his original association bonus in 2015.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yes, the reputation is the same as originally. Which corresponds to the fact that the user has at least one deleted post (see the previous comment). So if it was deleted not too long ago, it would correspond to starting at 101, increasing the reputation to 106 after an upvote on the question and going back to 101 after the question was deleted.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I will just mention that another possible explanation of the decrease of reputation could be "[user was removed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/337/loss-of-reputation-because-a-user-was-removed)" - as suggested by [S. Carnahan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2019/5/4). He also pointed out that the question I've mentioned in my previous comment was deleted in 2015 - so it cannot explain recent reputation decrease. (As I've mentioned, since I am below 10k, I wasn't able to check when the question was deleted.)